# Does the sequence length of a RNN/LSTM have to be the same for the input and output?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a question about the input and output data in a RNN or LSTM. A RNN expects a 3-dimensional vector as input of the form (Batch_size, sequence_length_input, features_input) and a 3-dimensional output vector of the form (Batch_size, sequence_length_output, features_output).

I know that the features_input and features_output don't have to have the same number while the Batch_size has to be equal for input and output. But what about the middle part sequence_length_input and sequence_length_output. Do they have to be the same? At least in my example (with Keras and Tensorflow) I always get an error if they are not the same. So I am wondering whetever I have a bug in the code or if this is generally not possible.

So can I for example use as input for the training, the data X_train =(1000, 100, 10) and the output Y_train = (1000, 20, 3) such that I have a mapping for each of the 1000 itmes (Batch_size) from a 10-dimensional (features_input) time series with 100 time steps (sequence_length_input) to a 3-dimensional (features_output) time series with 20 time steps (sequence_length_output).

**Update**: Here is my code with a RNN for time series forecasting that only works if the sequence_length of the input `steps_backward` is equal to the sequence_length of the output `steps_forward` otherwise it will throw a ValueError:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 192 and 96 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](sequential_5/time_distributed_5/Reshape_1, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,192,1], [?,96,1].
```

In the code I use the 96 past timesteps (or 2*96=192 timesteps) to predict the future 96 timesteps. When the number of past and future timesteps are equal (equal sequence_length), everything works fine. Otherwise (unequal sequence_length) I get the ValueError.

Code:

```
#Import modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from tensorflow import keras

# Define the parameters of the RNN and the training
epochs = 1
batch_size = 50
steps_backwards = 2 * 96
steps_forward = 96
split_fraction_trainingData = 0.70
split_fraction_validatinData = 0.90
randomSeedNumber = 50

#Read dataset
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User1/Desktop/TestData.csv', sep=';', header=0, low_memory=False, infer_datetime_format=True, parse_dates={'datetime':[0]}, index_col=['datetime'])

# standardize data

data = df.values
indexWithYLabelsInData = 0
data_X = data[:, 0:3]
data_Y = data[:, indexWithYLabelsInData].reshape(-1, 1)


scaler_standardized_X = StandardScaler()
data_X = scaler_standardized_X.fit_transform(data_X)
data_X = pd.DataFrame(data_X)
scaler_standardized_Y = StandardScaler()
data_Y = scaler_standardized_Y.fit_transform(data_Y)
data_Y = pd.DataFrame(data_Y)


# Prepare the input data for the RNN

series_reshaped_X =  np.array([data_X[i:i + (steps_backwards+steps_forward)].copy() for i in range(len(data) - (steps_backwards+steps_forward))])
series_reshaped_Y =  np.array([data_Y[i:i + (steps_backwards+steps_forward)].copy() for i in range(len(data) - (steps_backwards+steps_forward))])


timeslot_x_train_end = int(len(series_reshaped_X)* split_fraction_trainingData)
timeslot_x_valid_end = int(len(series_reshaped_X)* split_fraction_validatinData)

X_train = series_reshaped_X[:timeslot_x_train_end, :steps_backwards] 
X_valid = series_reshaped_X[timeslot_x_train_end:timeslot_x_valid_end, :steps_backwards] 
X_test = series_reshaped_X[timeslot_x_valid_end:, :steps_backwards] 

   
Y_train = series_reshaped_Y[:timeslot_x_train_end, steps_backwards:] 
Y_valid = series_reshaped_Y[timeslot_x_train_end:timeslot_x_valid_end, steps_backwards:] 
Y_test = series_reshaped_Y[timeslot_x_valid_end:, steps_backwards:]                                
   
   
# Build the model and train it

np.random.seed(randomSeedNumber)
tf.random.set_seed(randomSeedNumber)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(10, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None, 3]),
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(10, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(1))
])

model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam")
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid))

#Predict the test data
Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

and here is some test data https://filetransfer.io/data-package/ufbzh09o#link

**Reminder**: The code and the data provide a Minimal reproducible example. Maybe you can have a look at it as in this code the sequence_length has to be equal for the input and output data, otherwise I get an error. Unfortuantely I still have not figured out why this this problem occurs

Comment: Yes, input and output can differ in shape. But all inputs have to be the same shape and all outputs have to be the same shape also. Try printing the shapes of  your data. This will help you debug it better.

Comment: @Marcus: Thanks for your comment. In my example all the inputs and outputs have the same shape no matter if the sequence_length are equal or not. In the case of equal sequence_lenght, the input has the shape (Batchsize, 96, 3) and the output (Batchsize, 96,1). This works well. But when the sequence_length is different, the input has the shape (Batchsize, 192, 3) and the output (Batchsize, 96, 1). This leads to an error `ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 192 and 96`. So the problem is not - as you might have suggested - that there are differences within the input or output data.

Comment: The code and the data provide a Minimal reproducible example. Maybe you can have a look at it as in this code the sequence_length has to be equal for the input and output data, otherwise I get an error. Unfortuantely I still have not figured out why this this problem occurs.

Comment: @Marcus: Any comments to my last comments? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: What is the output supposed to be? You take in the data, which seems to be a time series, and then what? Classify it? Predict it? Also, how are you processing your data? If you look at data_X and data_Y you'll see that Y is the fist column of X. Why would you keep the output in the input? I also don't understand why you keep some of the other features. First try to define the problem you're trying to solve. Then prepare the data and keep track of the shapes then create the model you need with proper input and output shapes based on your data.

Comment: @Marcus: Thanks for your comment. I really appreciate it. As written in the short description, I am using the past values of a time series to predict its future values. This is why data_Y is the first column of data_X (the column is the feature I am trying to predict). If you have a closer look at how I prepare the training data for X and Y, you'll see that for the input X data I use the past data per batch from 0 to `:steps_backwards`, whereas for the label Y data I use the following data starting from `steps_backwards:` (note the different position of the `:`)

Comment: @Marcus: Thanks for your comments Marcus. Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problems. My input data shape is [512,10,3], and the output data is [512,20,1], which means that the last ten-time time steps data is used to predict the future twenty-time time steps. When I tried to implement it in PyTorch, the same problem as you appeared. Finally, I just used the last state of the LSTM to repeat 20 times and feed into the next fully connected layers. However, I cannot do it in the classic backpropagation (just made up of fully connected layers) neural network.